# Use Button instead of FloatingActionButton with AppBarLayout anchor in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have a problem with using a normal Button and setting the AppBarLayout as the anchor to that Button as the upper part of the Button is placed under the AppBarLayout. It works when using a `FloatingActionButton` and I have tried to set elevation and using `bringToFront`, but nothing works.

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ​
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        ​​​
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/materialup.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|snap"
            style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack"
            />
        ​
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/materialup.title_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
            ​
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:text="@string/title_mup_name"
                />
            ​
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
                android:text="@string/subtitle_mup"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                />
            ​
        </LinearLayout>
        ​
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ​
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/materialup.viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
    ​

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit_trip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/materialup.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Submit"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: do you want your button to move up along with your appBar while scrolling up?? or is the appBar fixed not scrollable ??

Comment: @SantanuSur Yup and all that is working as part of the coordinator layout already, the only thing that is not working is that the button is displayed as half, but it scrolls and behaves correctly

Comment: try wrapping up the coordinator layout inside a constraint layout and then keep the button inside the constraint layout

Comment: good question btw ..:) wish i was in front pc ryt now ..would have enjoyed solving it ..

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with the Behavior, but I still couldn't figure it out. If I'm gonna use the ConstraintLayout, I'll be losing the scrolling behavior that I have now!

Comment: cool , but you are using `app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|snap"` ryt ?? i.e you are not pinning the toolbar ..it can enter under the `statusbar` so why not use a `scrollView` with a **constraintLayout as immediate child** ..instead..??

Comment: @SantanuSur Aha, no I have to scroll it, but didn't get to this part yet!

Comment: @Ahmed Hegazy Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yup, I found a workaround. I'll post it later today!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your submit button inside Cardview and set elevation to the cardview. It will work. I used textview instead of button:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/materialup.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit_trip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try two possible solutions : first try to delete the padding_bottom from your linear layout in your appbar likewise you will minimize the surface of your appbar to let the button appear.
second add android:layout_marginTop to your button.
Let me know if that worked, if not we can search for other options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this won't work as I need it to be placed in this place

Comment: can you try to assign the button this : android:layout_weight="1"